# Link Query Returns non Zero String value from data base

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

One of my database table column is `varchar` that has only numeric entities.

My Linq Query is:

```
from ...
join ...
where (nsEvent == NULL|| a.NsEvent.Contains(""))
select ...
```

It returns all the values except the rows starting with '0' ie 0425, 0987 etc

Comment: How do you determine those rows are missing?

Comment: @Tony [LINQ operators are lowercase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx).

Comment: I check from back end

Comment: the above query is the link query i use it in .net

Comment: Yeah that's not enough. I'm sure that the Linq query you show does not cause the behavior you describe. You need to make sure those records are present and that they are queried correctly.

Comment: the column a.nsEvent contains numbers in string format

Comment: I agree but i checked the same query in both UI and SQL there was a difference. It exactly skiped the row that start with 0

Comment: I use the same query for all the other tables which has alphabets as entity it worked fine

Comment: *now  .. The problem is not with the code as i even commented the where and select condition of NSEvent. But don't know why my ASP.NET v.12 is not allowing the rows starting with '0' when my SQL allows.

Comment: Please some body help me to sort it out its like a mystery